# How do you stop tomcat after changing the shutdown word in server.xml?

Tags: security, tomcat

Running tomcat-7.0.33 on CentOS. I have a security requirement to change the tomcat shutdown word in server.xml to a random string of characters, so I need to go from this:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

to something like this

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="8GVsi4lMZTX6aOzorJYexiq8K7ZGxaZ">
```

However once that is in place, I cannot restart/stop tomcat via the init script (`/etc/init.d/tomcat stop`). When I attempt to, I get the following in my catalina.out:

```
Jul 22, 2014 8:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:499)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:453)
```

**Simple question**: how do I change the shutdown word in server.xml in such a way that I can use the init script just as I always would?
Or, if that does not have an answer, when I change the shutdown word in server.xml, how do I go about restarting/stopping the tomcat service?

Comment: It seems pretty likely that your init script either has the word hard coded in the script, or in a configuration file the script reads.  Have you reviewed how the existing script actually initiates a shutdown?

Comment: Modify script to output the PID to a file, then use this to send kill signal.  This is pretty standard and this is a drawback to disabling shutdown port, the default script uses the shutdown port.  If you telnet to this port, you shutdown tomcat, so this is why security wants you to disable it:)